# Parsing nested JSON data and assigning it to Spinners in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I need to parse following nested JSON data and assign it to Spinners in my Android Activity. What would be the best way to parse this JSON data. So that i can show values inside spinners and on submitting the data ID of that particular selected value should passed.

```
{
   "root":[
      {
         "genderList":[
            {
               "gender_id":"1",
               "gender_name":"Male"
            },
            {
               "gender_id":"2",
               "gender_name":"Female"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "SocialCategory":[
            {
               "SOCIAL_CATEGORY_ID":"1",
               "SOCIAL_CATEGORY_NAME":"General"
            },
            {
               "SOCIAL_CATEGORY_ID":"2",
               "SOCIAL_CATEGORY_NAME":"SC"
            },
            {
               "SOCIAL_CATEGORY_ID":"3",
               "SOCIAL_CATEGORY_NAME":"ST"
            },
            {
               "SOCIAL_CATEGORY_ID":"4",
               "SOCIAL_CATEGORY_NAME":"OBC"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: what do you want to show on spinner ? SocialCategory or genderList or both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to have custom classes that represent the data you want to show. Then you need to parse the JSON objects and create the instances and add them to arrays or lists. And then you need to create two adapters (one for each type of data) - the best way is to extend the BaseAdapter as a more flexible approach. After assigning the adapters to the spinners you can get the whole object from the selected position. In the same time you show only what is needed - the adapter defines the view.

**This code is not tested**, but you will get the idea of how to parse JSON in Android.

```
    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray rootArray = responseJson.getJSONArray("root");

    JSONObject genderListWrapperJson = rootArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray genderListJsonArray = genderListWrapperJson.getJSONArray("genderList");

    for (int i = 0; i < genderListJsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject genderJson = genderListJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String genderId = genderJson.getString("gender_id");
        String genderName = genderJson.getString("gender_name");
        // TODO: instantiate an object of custom type gender
    }

    JSONObject socialCategoryWrapperJson = rootArray.getJSONObject(1);
    JSONArray socialCategoryJsonArray = socialCategoryWrapperJson.getJSONArray("SocialCategory");

    for (int i = 0; i < socialCategoryJsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject socialCategoryJson = socialCategoryJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String categoryId = socialCategoryJson.getString("SOCIAL_CATEGORY_ID");
        String categoryName = socialCategoryJson.getString("SOCIAL_CATEGORY_NAME");
        // TODO: instantiate an object of custom social category
    }
```

"response" is the JSON text you have.